# Wavefront .OBJ Import Error

Tags: import

I'm getting an error message when I try to import an .OBJ file that I've generated from another .blend file. I'm pretty new to Blender, and I really don't know what it is that the error message is telling me, or how to fix it. Can you help?

[image: OBJ Import error message]

Comment: At a glance, maybe duplicate verts or some other thing not supported, can you share the original file?

Comment: @iKlsR   It's here, at [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33836019/sideskirts.blend. File size is about 4 MB.

Comment: I think this bug has been fixed, can you try this with a recent build? Otherwise please report a bug with the OBJ and Blend file.

Answer (score 1):

That exports and imports perfectly for me, Blender 2.77. However, it's as I suspected, there are a bunch of duplicate vertices which are no doubt causing the error on your end.

To fix, box select <kbd>B</kbd> your entire model, join it into one mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, select all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, open special menu <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Remove Doubles*. Finally, select everything again in edit mode and use <kbd>P</kbd> *> Separate by loose parts*. You will have to reassign any materials, fix origins and groups after but that should fix the problem and give you a clean obj.

Comment: For what it's worth, the _Remove Doubles_ process worked to clean up the file, after which an OBJ exported from it imported to another file without issues.

Comment: @PeterFitzpatrick great, next time it would probably help to try the latest version of Blender as well.